# Wordpress site not working on all browers

Tags: html, wordpress-theming

please if any one can help me... my site under wordpress which is http://mobiles.bitsedge.com/ does not work in IE or Opera but works well in Mozila Firfox.

I do not know how to handle it. it looks very horrible. thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be good to site specific examples of what rendering you feel is not working in ie and opera

Comment: when you develop you should consider how your page looks under different monitor size,

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 'width="668"' from your td elements

Comment: sir what is td elements? can you please suggest me any good visual wp editor

Answer (score 0):

check the css of your site.It may not compatible with IE.